# flutter build apk to only update changes

Tags: flutter

I use flutter build apk on a headless IDE (C9) on a chromebook. I can sideload the created APK easy on the chromebook itself (it runs android). But, building takes 1 or 2 minutes every time. Is there a way of hot-rebuilding the APK so it goes faster?

I am building from command line!

Answer (score 1):

goto `run` -> and press `flutter hot reload` or `cntrl+\`